# Ionic: compileSdkVersion is not specified - Could not find method leftShift()

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I've just started my app with Ionic 4. For the moment I never made any modification to the original code you have (with the sidemenu) when you start the project.
After many other errors, I've this one that I don't know how to fix it.
It happen when I try to:

> ionic cordova build android

```
    FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'D:\workspace\iganalytics\app\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 148

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method leftShift() for arguments [build_8ka4my3njl1nfn72j8pdlyfze$_run_closure6@5b9f348] on task ':app:cdvPrintProps' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'D:\workspace\iganalytics\app\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 148

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method leftShift() for arguments [build_8ka4my3njl1nfn72j8pdlyfze$_run_closure6@5b9f348] on task ':app:cdvPrintProps' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I added this line to config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
```

With no luck.

build.gradle line 148 start with:

```
task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit=' + cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed android skd version 28 in android studio?.

Comment: What version of cordova-android and gradle are you using?

Comment: @AnandhSp Yes I have

Comment: @JayOrdway Android 7 and gradle 5.2.1

Answer (score 4):

Managed to make it work by adding platform android@8 instead of only android which install version 7

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem. The solution was updating to android@8. Thanks @Splinteer.
Here is some more detail on how to do this:

list your platforms with:

```
ionic cordova platform list
```

remove android with:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

add android@8:

```
ionic cordova platform add android@8
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue yesterday and fixed by adding `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />` in the config.xml

Comment: This may not be a good long-term solution, if the requirement for Play Store is 26: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk